# How to extract the elapsed time from a timer object in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to extract the elapsed time from the beginning of each period from a timer object in MATLAB?
Say we have a timer object like this:

```
t=timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
    'Period', 15, ...                 
    'TimerFcn',@(x,y)disp('Hello World!'))
```

Comment: `tic`  `toc` may be used for this purpose!

Answer (score 2):

The `y` contains the absolute timestamp. Store it when the timer is stated and take the difference:

```
function my_callback(m,x,y)
persistent starttime
switch m
    case 'start'
        starttime=y.Data.time;
    case 'timer'
        disp(datenum(y.Data.time-starttime)*24*60*60);
    otherwise
        error('unknown argument');
end
end
```

With a timer:

```
t=timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','Period', 15,'StartFcn',@(x,y)my_callback('start',x,y),'TimerFcn',@(x,y)my_callback('timer',x,y))
start(t)
```

Alternative solution using userdata:

```
 t=timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate','Period', 15,'StartFcn',@(x,y)set(x,'UserData',y.Data.time),'TimerFcn',@(x,y)disp(datenum(y.Data.time-get(x,'UserData'))*24*60*60))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach using `tic`, `toc` and `'UserData'`**

There is no direct method on the `timer`-object to read the elapsed time since its last call. It is possible to use a construct with `tic` and `toc` to achieve what you want.

The generic field `'UserData'` can be used to add user-data to the timer object. We can write this value with `set()` and read it with `get()`. So we set this value with `tic` in the callback-function and get it back later to compute the time difference using `toc`.

More specifically, here is the callback-function:

```
function timerCallback(timerObj,event) %#ok<INUSD>
disp('Hello World!');
set(timerObj,'UserData',tic);
```

Now we can write a wrapper-function to get the elapsed time:

```
function retval = getElapsedTime(timerObj)
retval = toc(get(timerObj,'UserData'));
```

---

**Example usage of proposed approach**

To see if this approach works, we use `pause` to wait in a for loop and read the elapsed time approximately every second. Here is a complete example:

```
function timer_example
t = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...
          'Period', 5, ...                 
          'TimerFcn', @timerCallback);  % create timer
start(t);                               % start timer
pause on;                               % make sure pause can be used
for i = 1:10
    pause(1);                           % wait a second
    disp(getElapsedTime(t));            % display the elapsed time
end
stop(t);                                % stop timer
delete(t);                              % delete timer

function timerCallback(timerObj,event)  %#ok<INUSD>
disp('Hello World!');
set(timerObj,'UserData',tic);

function retval = getElapsedTime(timerObj)
retval = toc(get(timerObj,'UserData'));
```

*This gives the following output:*

```
>> timer_example
Hello World!
    1.0163
    2.0173
    3.0235
    4.0285
Hello World!
    0.0366
    1.0390
    2.0427
    3.0461
    4.0470
Hello World!
    0.0515
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tic as StartFcn of your timer and then use toc to elicit elapsed time, so:

```
timerObj = timer; %create timer object
timerObj.ExecutionMode = 'fixedSpacing';
timerObj.Period = 15; 
timerObj.StartFcn = @(~,~)tic; % start ticking when timer starts
timerObj.TimerFcn = @myTimerFunc;
```

myTimerFunc is:

```
function [] = myTimerFunc(timerObj,event)
% use toc 
disp(toc);   
end
```